# select specific value with awk (using array)

Tags: bash, unix, awk

How to select specific value with an array using awk.

Data

```
,,20160112,161521,139,
```

Example awk

```
awk -F "," '$3==`20160112` {print $3}'
```

Expectation is i want to select within the date range, not only single values, such like below. but below code is not working.

```
awk -F "," '$3==`201601[01-10]` {print $3}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your date format is fixed `YYYYMMDD`, this line should work for you:

```
awk -F, '$3>="20160101"&&$3<="20160110"{print $3}' file
```

Comment: Are the quotes necessary?